# extract elements from rows/columns

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(35).reshape(7,5)
print (data)
```

[image]

I wanted to extract elements inside red.

```
result = data[-3:, -2:]
```

print (result)

```
[[23 24]
 [28 29]
 [33 34]]
```

wrong!

how is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, but your `-2` is on the wrong side of the `:`

You want to access from the last 3 rows, but only *up until* the last 2 columns:

```
In [52]: data[-3:, :-2]
Out[52]:
array([[20, 21, 22],
       [25, 26, 27],
       [30, 31, 32]])
```

`-2:` == Last two columns

`:-2` == Up until the last two columns

If you explicitly want the last 3 rows and the first 3 columns, you could also use:

```
In [53]: data[-3:, :3]
Out[53]:
array([[20, 21, 22],
       [25, 26, 27],
       [30, 31, 32]])
```

Comment: thanks, accept! but, in `data[-3:, :3]`, `:3` is very confusing. could you remove my confusion?

Comment: The first `-3:` represents the last 3 rows, the `:3` represents up to the third column.

Answer (score 1):

elegant and perfect:

```
result = data[-3:, :3]
```